# How to create python exe by py2exe with OpenCV functionality

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, exe, py2exe

I have successfully prepared an exe using py2exe. My source code contains opencv functionality. I wish to run this exe at a computer where opencv is not pre-installed. Please provide me a solution.

My setup file is as follows:

## ---------------------------------------------------------------

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import numpy
import cv2
import matplotlib
from PIL import Image

setup(
    console = ['main_program.py'],
    options = {
                'py2exe': 
                { 
                    'includes' : ['cv2', 'numpy'],

```
                'excludes': ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg', '_agg2', '_cairo','_cocoaagg', 
                              "matplotlib.numerix.fft","sip", "PyQt4._qt",
                              "matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg",
                              "matplotlib.numerix.linear_algebra", 
                              "matplotlib.numerix.random_array",
                             '_fltkagg', '_gtk','_gtkcairo'],

                'dll_excludes': 
                [
                    'libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
                    'libgobject-2.0-0.dll' ,
                     ......
                     ......
                     ......
```

Comment: all required libraries will be added automatically, if its not you have to traceback and include that library

Comment: Getting the error after doing as your suggestion: error: bundle-files 1 not yet supported on win64

Comment: Getting error => error: bundle-files 1 not yet supported on win64

Comment: for win64 its not supported. check whether all required libraries and dependencies are imported. else add it manually in include section

Comment: Hi Mohan, I have successfully prepared the exe and it is working at my computer where, opencv is pre-installed  with python Anaconda distribution. But, I am facing error while to run that exe on another pc where opencv is not installed. How to overcome this issue ?

Comment: Try using pyinstaller. I doubt that py2exe is missing some of the dependencies. What is the error code returned? Also try to copy the opencv dll to bundled folder. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477643/packaging-opencv-with-a-python-app for further.