# How to Destribute python and openCV based tool as single setup file with all the dependencies

Tags: python, opencv

I have develop  a python based tool. This tool basically based on Computer vision. I have used openCV and python to develop entire programme along with the GUI. But when i use this programming on different machine i need to install all the dependencies first like openCV, pandas, kivy and matplotlib. I want to distribute this program  as setup file, specifically for windows so that no one need to install opencv and all dependencies. Installation of openCV is a tricky job and i want user should bother only about the software uses not the installation and other technicality

I know few tools suggested by some previous posts but they din't explain the integration of OpenCV along with the python installer.

Comment: @Dan Mašek Thanks but this post does not solve my problem because python alone is not my problem. My main concern is python along with the OpenCV with python binding.

Comment: py2exe (the tool in dan's link) bundles any dependant dlls (eg OpenCV) automatically - or at least it used to.

Comment: @jax I'm pretty sure it does, it describes several different ways of distributing python applications along with the dependencies, of which OpenCV would be one. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477643/packaging-opencv-with-a-python-app) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811423/opencv-with-standalone-python-executable-py2exe-pyinstaller) and many other similar questions.